# Create string in MessageBox or WriteLine

Tags: c#, string, messagebox

I have a question, I don't really need it for the application at the moment but I was just curious.

Is there a way to create a string and fill it between the parentheses of WriteLine or Messagebox.Show ?

The code should then look something like this I think:

```
MessageBox.Show(String s = string.Format("Hello World"));
```

That is not the correct code, my only **question** is: Is something like that possible?

Comment: It might be better if you explained **why** and **what** you hope to accomplish rather than asking about a possible and seemingly incongruous solution. =)

Comment: You should add a requirement to your question, because the presented example makes no sense, will not compile and does not make it clear what exactly you are asking for.

Comment: That's usually a bad reason, and destroys readability. Again, I ask, why? Do you expect to use `s` elsewhere? =)

Comment: jup, if you could make it public

Comment: I hope I never see something like that when working with someone else's code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can declare a string inside a call like that. However you can assign it.

```
string s = string.Empty;
MessageBox.Show(s = string.Format("Hello World"));
```

If you could declare strings inside a functioncall it wouldnt be visible elsewhere. So it woulndt really make any sense having that functionality in the language.

Comment: Okay, thanks, but isn't there a way to also create the string between the parentheses?

Comment: To note: you're not declaring the string inside the call. You're assigning it. And it only works because the return value of the assignment is the assigned variable.

Comment: @Evelie thanks for editing the post, you give a good argument about why it is not possible.

Comment: if you are talking about using something likes `string someString = "Ugly"` `string.Format("Hello {0} World", someString));` then the msg would read `Hello Ugly World` then this might be what you are looking for , then the answer would be no but you can pass a string variable between the parentheses

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Evelie's answer that lets you write it all in one line could be to define a helper method returning a string:

```
public static string ShowMsg(string msg) {
    MessageBox.Show(msg);
    return msg;
}
```

And your code would become:

```
string s = ShowMsg("Hello World");
```

or

```
string s = ShowMsg(string.Format("Now is {0}.", DateTime.Now));
```

And you could also perform the formatting inside your helper method:

```
public static string ShowMsg(string format, params object[] args) {
    string mgs = string.Format(format, args);
    MessageBox.Show(msg);
    return msg;
}
```

And use it as:

```
string s = ShowMsg("Now is {0}.", DateTime.Now);
```